# Printing IFS values from file

Tags: linux, shell, parsing, ksh

Script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILENAME=$1

while read RECORD VALUE
do      
    echo  ${RECORD}  ${VALUE} "X"       

done <"$FILENAME"
```

input file:

```
A 1
B 2
```

The output of script:

```
 X1
 X2
```

If I remove from echo "x", e.g.

```
echo  ${RECORD}  ${VALUE}
```

I am getting

```
A 1
B 2
```

what is wrong?

Update:
If I do

```
echo  "X" ${RECORD}  ${VALUE}
```

it prints correctly:

```
X A 1
X B 2
```

and :

```
  echo  ${RECORD} "X"
```

also prints correctly, so i am guessing the issues is with VALUE that maybe contains return carriage symbol (as input file was created on windows)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error (i'm on os x 10.9.5). how are you running your script ... like `ksh script inputfile`?

Comment: . myscript.sh file.txt

Answer (score 0):

adding this inside the loop:

```
VALUE=`echo $VALUE| tr -d '\r'`
```

solved the issue, if you have a better solution you are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter expansion operator you can use to remove a character from the end of a value, if it is present.

```
VALUE=${VALUE%$'\r'}
```

This is handled in-shell, without needing to start a new process.